# Laravel: Remove storage files created by Storage facade from Command class

Tags: php, laravel, cron, scheduler

I'm using Laravel storage facade to storage images in my Laravel Application. Both owner and group of storage files created by Storage facade is www-data. I'm using Scheduler to trigger my command which posts images to tumblr with their API.

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
         Commands\PublishPosts::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('posts:publish')
                ->everyThirtyMinutes()
                ->timezone('Asia/Karachi')
                ->when(function () {
                    return date('H') >= 0 && date('H') <= 5;
                });
    }
}
```

My cron job will call the Laravel command scheduler and post images to Tumblr.

```
* * * * * php /var/www/laravel/blogbits/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

After successfully posting image, my command method removes image.

```
/**
 * Post a batch of posts
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function publishPostBatch(){
    $posts = Post::take($this->getBatchPostLimit())->get();
    foreach ($posts as $post){
        if($this->createPost($post)){
            $post->delete();
            $this->deleteImage($post->file_name);
        }
    }
}
```

But because the scheduler is triggered by cron job which was initiated by my username rather than apache www-data user or group, it fails to delete the image stored in storage path. Is there any way i can modify the user of file created by storage facade? Or is there a better way to handle this situation?

Comment: Try these two commands to change the permissions and ownership: `sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage` and `sudo chmod -R 777 storage`. You may also need to mess with the groups, and add `www-data` to your user's group.

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 777 storage` updates the current files permission in the storage/ directory. New uploads by application still have www-data:www-data user and group. I don't want to run chmod command every time i upload new files to my storage.

Comment: There's where the first chmod command comes in, along with adding the group.

Comment: Adding my user to www-data group didn't help. New storage files have `rw-r--r-- 644` permission when they are created.